# Salesforce Org Autorize Error

Tags: vs-code, cli, authorization, sfdx-error

Hi guys I have a problem with authorize to my Sandbox, I used this command to authorize "login --setalias "MyOrg" --instanceurl "MyOrgUrl" --setdefaultusername" and getting this errors: [image][image]

Also I can't to open list of my orgs by clicking this button but day before all worked as expected:
[image]

I tried to update sfdx, cli, npm.

Tried to delete files from folders "/.sf" and "/.sfdx".

Refresh the Org.

And nothing helped me, I really need help please

Answer (score 0):

You can try restarting your code editor, I assume you are using VsCode. See if that helps.

Then type this command in your CLI, to see the list of orgs and their status:

```
sf org list
```

and (the below, to see  [List authorization information about the orgs you created or logged into.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_org_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_org_list_auth_unified))

```
sf org list auth
```

Else you can authorize to your sandbox using the following command found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_org_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_org_login_web_unified).

Here I have extracted the command from the documentation mentioned.

```
sf org login device --instance-url https://MyDomainName--SandboxName.sandbox.my.salesforce.com
```

Please note in the commands **below**, I have added **--alias** at the back, so that you can name it, in a way you can remember.

Make sure you change the part after --instance-url, to the url of your sandbox. This part, (https://**MyDomainName**--**SandboxName**), you have to change the parts, I have bolded for you and additionally added the --alias command too.

So in conclusion, just change {THIS}, make sure you remove the curly braces (You can name the alias, whatever you want, to remember the sandbox org, for example myPersonalSandbox):

```
sf org login device --instance-url https://{THIS}--{THIS}.sandbox.my.salesforce.com --alias {THIS}
```

Let's say for example, my sandbox url looks something like this:

> https://test1-test2--test3.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home

So to connect to this org, I would type in the following command in my cli:

```
sf org login device --instance-url https://test1-test2--test3.sandbox.my.salesforce.com --alias myTestSandbox
```

If it was like this,

> https://test1--test2.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/page/home

then my command would be:

```
sf org login device --instance-url https://test1--test2.sandbox.my.salesforce.com --alias myTestSandbox
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, this way didn't help me.

Comment: I see, did you try and check if there are any orgs in list of orgs by running sf org list?

Comment: Yes, it gave me error: 
Error (1): Parse error in file unknown on line 20
cksSource": false
}
}